# why the results of Benchmark and StopWatch so different?

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking, stopwatch

i want to measure a method's performance and use the two different way, but the results is confused me.

Method 1:

```
new Test().Main();

public class Test
{
    
    public void Main()
    {
        long a = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
            
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            long b = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            Console.WriteLine(Stopwatch.GetElapsedTime(a,b)); // output:00:00:00.0008388 = 8388us
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Test
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void Main1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jIyn.png)

the measure ways i used is right? if that's right, why the results is so different?(8388us vs 258us) and which result should i rely for measure performance?

Comment: You should be using a profiler, ideally.

Comment: 258us is a plausible result for a ~3.9GHz processor doing a million iterations of a trivial loop. 8388us is absurd.

Comment: Are you running this in a debug build or a prod build. You may find that the optimizer eliminates your trivial loop in some cases

Comment: @Flydog57 its running on release build. im using rider 2023.3.2

Comment: Try to remove the try-finally block.

Comment: BTW if you're running benchmarks manually like that, without a benchmarking framework, the least you should do is run it multiple times. Don't take the average, just print all the results, you'll see them going down very quickly and then settle around a number that's much lower than the first time.

Comment: @shingo i removed the block and the result is no much different then before.